# Dirac Delta Function definition with ksi (ξ)

Tags: notation, definition, dirac-delta

The dirac delta function has a definition

$$f(0)=\int_∞^∞f(x)δ(x)dx$$

and

$$ f(x)=\int_∞^∞f(x-ξ)δ(ξ)dξ $$

(the lower bound is minus infinity but I couldn't add a minus :/)

I do understand the first definition but I don't understand the second one. What is the idea behind the second notation with the ksi's?

I would appreciate it if someone could explain this/give the name of this type of notation so I can search a little further.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I really dislike the "definition" with an integral, as it is not an integral in the usual sense, and the dirac is not a function from a real (or complex)variable

Comment: Perhaps the strictly equivalent formula, based, for every fixed $u$, on the function $g_u:x\mapsto f(u-x)$, $$f(u)=g_u(0)=\int_{-∞}^∞g_u(x)δ(x)dx=\int_{-∞}^∞f(u-x)δ(x)dx$$
is less problematic to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating $f(x)$ against $\delta(x)$ gives $f(0)$, that is, evaluates $f$ at $x=0$.

In the second integral, let $g(\xi)=f(x-\xi)$, where $\xi$ is the variable and $x$ a parameter. Integrating $g(\xi)$ against $\delta(\xi)$ gives $g(0)=f(x)$.